# Xcode 8 seems to be incorrectly changing embedded framework function signature with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have a linked framework that has a class called LoginViewController.h

With Swift 2.3, using this class worked just fine. The function in question is this one:

```
-(void)startLoginWithSuccessHandler: (LoginSuccessHandler)successHandler failureHandler:(LoginFailureHandler)failureHandler;
```

At the top of the class there are some typedefs:

```
typedef void (^LoginSuccessHandler)();
typedef void (^LoginFailureHandler)(NSError *error);
```

I have a function that calls *startLoginWithSuccessHandler( )*:

```
func showLogin(){
    //Does some stuff
    loginViewController.startLoginWithSuccessHandler( { () -> Void in
       //Does more stuff

       }) { (error:NSError!) -> Void in
          //More stuff
       }
}
```

As you see above, this code worked just fine and my app runs and performs as expected.

When I used the Swift 3 migration tool, one of the errors came from this function call. It appears Xcode completely changed the way the method was called:

```
func showLogin() {
     //Does some stuff
     loginViewController.startLogin(successHandler: { () -> Void in
        //Does more stuff

       }) { (error:NSError!) -> Void in
           //More stuff
       }
}
```

It is clear that Xcode tried to convert the method signature to match the new Swift 3 conventions. However, this is a function inside a framework written in Obj-C, so the actual function is supposed to remain the way it is.

Furthermore, the actual error I am getting in Xcode occurs with this line:

```
{ (error:NSError!) -> Void in
```

And it says:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'LoginFailureHandler!'
```

I'm wondering if this is a bug or if there is an actual workaround/fix for this.

Answer (score 2):

You have no need to worry about this:
*this is a function inside a framework written in Obj-C, so the actual function is supposed to remain the way it is.*

Swift has some mapping rule and it generates the right Objective-C selectors for methods imported from Objective-C code.

You can find this code (put it where `loginViewController` is visible) showing `true`.

```
print(#selector(loginViewController.startLogin(successHandler:failureHandler:))
    == Selector("startLoginWithSuccessHandler:failureHandler:"))
```

And with this:

```
{ (error:NSError!) -> Void in
```

Swift 3 imports `NSError` as `Error`. Try changing the line with this:

```
{ (error: Error?) -> Void in
```

If you want to use it as `NSError`, simple `as` casting should work:

```
let nsError = error as NSError?
```